# HAVING SUM issue

Tags: mysql, sum, conditional-statements, having

I have a question about the statement HAVING SUM.

```
My table:

id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
date date
number int(3)

+----+------------+--------+
| id | date       | number |
+----+------------+--------+    
| 1  | 2010-01-02 |   0    |
| 2  | 2010-01-03 |   3    |
| 3  | 2010-01-04 |   0    |
| 4  | 2010-01-05 |   2    |
| 5  | 2010-01-06 |   1    |
| 6  | 2010-01-07 |   3    |
+----+------------+--------+
```

I would like return the date when the `SUM` of number is 6 and `date` > `'2010-01-04'`

I want return the date when the addition of the field number is equal to 6 (after a specific date, 2010-01-04 in this example). Example : my query should return 2010-01-07 because 2 in 2010-01-05 1 in 2010-01-06 3 in 2010-01-07

I've tested this query without success:

```
SELECT date, SUM(number) AS total FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY date
HAVING SUM(number) = 6
```

Comment: Even after updating your question, it is still not clear where you want to begin the rolling sum.

Comment: What if number in the last row was a 4? The result would never equal 6. So, what then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select date 
    from 
      (select date, @n:=@n+total total 
          from 
            (select date, sum(number) total 
                from MyTable 
              where date > '2010-01-04' 
              group by date 
              order by date 
            ) t 
           cross join 
            (select @n:=0) n 
      ) tt 
   where total = 6
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tested your answers. the both works =)

Comment: Splash58, i have use your code (but i'm change select date by select MAX(date) ).

Do you have an idea if the loop couldn't return the date expected (if it not present in database), In this case, i don't want a return of MAX(date) and no result

In this way i can set up an error msg with my PHP script... 

thanks =)

Comment: when you use group function mysql returns result. I think you will receive no row if ask date but max(date)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you *almost* had the right query in your original problem.  I added a `WHERE` clause to restrict to only dates which are more recent than `2010-01-04`:

```
SELECT date, SUM(number) AS total
FROM MyTable
WHERE date > '2010-01-04'
GROUP BY date
HAVING SUM(number) = 6
```

Comment: Based on the sample data you gave in the OP, there are no matching records.  Please edit your question and show us the table definition for `MyTable`.  Also it might be good if you show us a sample input which will generate a non-empty result set.

Comment: You would need to have a collection of records sharing a specific date whose number _sum_ were equal to 6.  The data sample you gave us only has one record per date, and the `number` values are all less than 6.

Comment: Your original question was not clear at all then.  Your requirement is totally different than what your OP implies.

Answer (score 0):

Think a self join is probably the easiest way to do it, joining your table against itself where the date is equal or larger than itself.

```
SELECT t1.date
FROM sometable t1
INNER JOIN sometable t2
ON t1.date <= t2.date
WHERE date > '2010-01-04'
GROUP BY t1.date
HAVING SUM(number) = 6
```